# Error 500: Handler processing failed&#59; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java/lang/String.isEmpty&#40;&#41;Z

Tags: java, spring, jsp, websphere, ibm-was

I have been facing this issue with my application(SPRING +JPA+JSP)  when i click on search button after selecting my search criteria.My search criteria has two dropdownbox,one textfield,one datepicker.The issue is coming with the value binding to textfield.After clicking on submit,it will make a ajax call with the following url :(It is expected to go to the controller class with the defined method name)

```
/Enquiry.page?methodName=loadList&
searchVo.selectedDisr.distCode=ALL&
searchVo.selectedSupplier.Code=ALL&searchVo.selectedDateAppr=
&searchVo.selectedproduct=
```

When i remove the request parameter  **&searchVo.selectedproduct=**    ,  it is working properly.If i keep that the following error is coming.

```
Error 500: Handler processing failed&#59; nested exception is    
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java/lang/String.isEmpty&#40;&#41;Z
```

**But the same code and url is working in tomcat 7 but not  working in IBM websphere.** I am facing this issue when i deploy my application in IBM WAS server.Please help me.

Comment: Check the JDK used by Tomcat and IBM. There should be difference. IBM has its own JDK. The method is available since 1.6. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty()

Comment: Yes,I have removed references to that method and it is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

isEmpty() method was added in Java 1.6. Most probably problem is you are using java 1.5 or lower version

Comment: I have removed the references to that method and it is working